# Mandelbrot set zoom limit

Tags: javascript, webgl, fractals, mandelbrot

I've recently started learning Javascript/ WebGL and I've learned enough to put together a simple Mandelbrot fractal renderer. The program works fine but for some reason it won't let me zoom in more than about 20 times, and it starts looking pixellated if I zoom in more. I've had this problem before in other fractal drawing programs I've made, but it usually doesn't become noticeable until about 2^45 zoom. I was thinking maybe it has to do with the max float size in GLSL, but I'm really not sure what the problem is or even how to go about finding the problem. I was just wondering if anyone knows what the cause of this zoom limit is and if there's any way I can increase it? Here's my HTML/ GLSL code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Mandelbrot Set</title>

    <style>

    body {
        margin = 0;
        padding = 0;
    }

    </style>

</head>


<body>

    <h3>Click on the fractal to zoom in.</h3>

    <canvas id = "canvas" width = "500" height = "500" onclick = "drawFractal();">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5.
    </canvas>

    <script id = "vertexshader" type = "vertexshader">

    attribute vec2 a_position;

    void main(){
        gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 0);
    }

    </script>

    <script id = "fragmentshader" type = "fragmentshader">

    precision mediump float;

    uniform vec2 u_resolution;
    uniform vec2 u_zoomCenter;
    uniform float u_zoom;
    uniform int u_maxIterations;
    uniform float u_colorDiversity;

    vec2 f(vec2 z, vec2 c)
    {
        return vec2(z.x*z.x - z.y*z.y, z.x*z.y*2.0) + c;
    }

    // Credit to hughsk on GitHub for this hsv to rgb converter
    vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c) {
        vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
        vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
        return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
    }

    void main(){

        vec2 zeroToOne = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;

        vec2 c = u_zoomCenter + (zeroToOne * 4.0 - vec2(2.0)) / u_zoom;
        vec2 z = vec2(0.0);
        bool escaped = false;
        float iterations = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            if (i > u_maxIterations) break;
            z = f(z, c);

            if (length(z) > 2.0)
            {
                escaped = true;
                iterations = float(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        gl_FragColor = escaped ? vec4(hsv2rgb(vec3(iterations * u_colorDiversity, 1.0, 1.0)), 1.0) : vec4(vec3(0.0), 1.0); 
    }

    </script>

    <script src = "webgl.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's my "webgl.js" file:

```
// Compile and link shaders and create program
function createShader(gl, type, source){
        var shader = gl.createShader(type);
        gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) return shader;

        console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        gl.deleteShader(shader);
        alert("Error: failed to create shader. Check the console for more information.");
}

function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader){
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);

    if (gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) return program;

    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
    alert("Error: failed to create program. Check the console for more information.");
}

// WebGL setup
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if (!gl){
    var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    console.log("WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental WebGL.");
}
if (!gl){
    console.log("Experimental WebGL not supported.");
    alert("Your browser does not support WebGL. Check the console for more information.");
}

// Create shaders and program
var vertexShaderSource = document.getElementById("vertexshader").text;
var fragmentShaderSource = document.getElementById("fragmentshader").text;

var vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
var fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);

var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
gl.useProgram(program);

// Set up position buffer
var screen = new Float32Array([
    -1, -1, 
    1, -1, 
    1, 1, 
    1, 1, 
    -1, 1, 
    -1, -1]);
var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, screen, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// Set up position attribute in vertex shader
var a_positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Set up WebGL window
gl.viewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

// Set up uniforms in fragment shader
var u_resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
var u_zoomCenterLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_zoomCenter");
var u_zoomLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_zoom");
var u_maxIterationsLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_maxIterations");
var u_colorDiversityLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_colorDiversity");

gl.uniform2f(u_resolutionLocation, 500, 500);

// Set up some global variables
var offset_x = 0;
var offset_y = 0;
var zoom = 1;
var iterations = 10000;
var colorDiversity = 0.01;

// Update uniforms based on global variables
function updateUniforms()
{
    gl.uniform2f(u_zoomCenterLocation, offset_x, offset_y);
    gl.uniform1f(u_zoomLocation, zoom);
    gl.uniform1i(u_maxIterationsLocation, iterations);
    gl.uniform1f(u_colorDiversityLocation, colorDiversity);
}

// Get mouse position
function getMousePos() {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return [(event.clientX - rect.left - 250) / 125, (event.clientY - rect.top - 250) / 125];
}

// Draw the fractal
function drawFractal() {
    mousePos = getMousePos();
    offset_x += mousePos[0] / zoom;
    offset_y -= mousePos[1] / zoom;
    zoom *= 2;

    updateUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

// Draw fractal when the page loads
updateUniforms();
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: that sounds more like too small `u_maxIterations` limit than accuracy problem ... I have [Mandelbrot implemented in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56197067/2521214) on 32bit `floats` and artifacts related to floating point precision are starting from zooms above `100000x` so 20 times zoom should not be a problem at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximal possible zoom depends on [the precision of the floating point number](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Computer_graphic_techniques/2D/plane#Maximal_zoom)  you use and your algorithm.

You can increase precision using arbitrary precision numbers, for example  [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/), [mpc](https://github.com/cran/mpc) or [arb library](http://arblib.org/)